# How can I rename a Keycloak role?

Tags: keycloak

**Is it somehow possible to rename a realm-role in Keycloak?**

[image]

It is not possible using the Keycloak UI.

But maybe a realm-role can be renamed directly in the database (we use PostgreSql)? Or using a REST API?

Comment: Pretty sure you can do it via DB, but why not just create a new role? migration issues on the field?

Comment: @dreamcrash yes, I already have dozens of users where I would need to remove the role and add the new role

Comment: You can make the new role a composite role of the old role, would that be a viable approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/21.0.1/rest-api/index.html) offers a put endpoint for this purpose.

```
PUT /{realm}/roles/{role-name}
```

In the body you'll pass on the new name of the role as a JSON - for example:

```
{
  "name": "my-new-role"
}
```

You need to have the necessary authorization to do this - you'll need to obtain an admin access token and pass it as a request header in the format:

```
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
```

In order to obtain the access token you can do:

```
curl \
-d "client_id=admin-cli" \
-d "username=admin" \
-d "password=password" \
-d "grant_type=password" \
"http://localhost:8080{kc_realms_path}/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

(more info: [Authenticating for Admin REST API](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/docs/documentation/server_development/topics/admin-rest-api.adoc))

Here's an example endpoint:

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/my-realm/roles/my-role
```

Comment: Thank you. Very good answer. I figured out you can also change the role name in the database (table `keycloak_role`) but this could change. That's why I prefer the API.